# How to align form inputs with different length of multiline labels side to side in bootstrap forms across browsers?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two divs in my form. They may have different lengths of their labels. I wish to align both the multiline text labels at top and the identical input divs to be centrally aligned with each other.

An example jsfiddle can be found below:

http://jsfiddle.net/ahujamoh/0v2fj4mc/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="first" class="control-label">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum </label>
        <input class="form-control" id="first">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="second" class="control-label">onsectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et onseclit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et </label>
        <input class="form-control" id="second">
    </div>
</div>
```

```
 .row {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.form-group .control-label{
    height:40px;
}
```

Actual: the top of text labels are aligned but the input boxes are not centrally aligned.

[image: Actual output]

Expected: the top of text labels are aligned and the input boxes are centrally aligned.

[image: Expected output]

Comment: text labels at to? I don't understand the question. Can you post an image of how you want the output to look like?

Comment: I have added an Actual output with a manually changed top margin for the 2nd input box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added the class `inputdiv` to each child of the `div` and convert that child to a `flexbox`.

```
 .row {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}


.inputdiv{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-height: 30vh;
}
```

I have set the `min-height` property to `30vh`. Feel free to play around with this value as you wish.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 inputdiv">
            <label for="first" class="control-label">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum </label>
            <input class="form-control" id="first">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 inputdiv">
            <label for="second" class="control-label">onsectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et onseclit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et </label>
            <input class="form-control" id="second">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to dynamically/auto-adjust the min-height?

Comment: Considering the number of lines for that div? It's a bit difficult